# c# mvc3 controls within a control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

MVC3 has entity framework that makes create, delete, edit methods within a controller. 
I am making a control panel that allows to edit multiple tables. How do I incorporate a controller(the entity framework) within another controller(the control panel)?

Any clever work around?

For example http://example.com/Control_panel/Another_Controller

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Please specify if you are talking about editing several tables from the same page or just have opportunity to open different pages for editing of different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for this, there are two ways lets say you have a default controlpanel action in your ControlPanel controller, you can have a variable that comes in and says what you are trying to control, lets call it controlID, you can then use RedirectToAction to go to that action instead, like this

```
public ActionResult controlPanel(object controlId){
     if(controlId.equals(something)){
         RedirectToAction(SomeAction, SomeController);
     }
}
```

The other one is you can use the same idea and call the controller action directly. Like this:

```
var result= new SomeController().SomeAction();
```

Although this is breaking MVC design as you should have it be a more universal function rather than a controller, as controllers are designed to control datamovement between Models and Views.  If I see some of the code I can give you a more specific response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit data from multiple tables from the same page, you accomplish this by use of view models. The data you present to the user in your view does not need to have a 1:1 relationship with a table or a model for that matter.

A view model will allow you to pick data from various sources, present the same to the user for viewing or editing and if the user saves the same, you can pick the view model from your controller action and use that data to update one or more tables.